# Postgres solving a syntax error caused by a dash (-)

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I am trying to query from a database called `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd`

PostgresSQL returns the following error message:

> ```
> quan.sql:273: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
> LINE 132: from `physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd` icd
> ```

I think it is caused by the dash. If I change the `for ' the same error comes up

> ```
> quan.sql:273: ERROR:  syntax error at or near
> "'physionet-data.mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd'"
> ```

Any clue on how to fix that?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to quote that schema name, using double-quotes:

```
select ...
from "physionet-data".mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd
```

Note that quoting an identifier makes it case-sensitive. You would need to ensure that the character case the schema was created with matches the one you are using here.

Using identifiers that require quoting is not a good idea in general; as you are fiding out, this requires quoting them every where you use it later on. If that's not too late, I would recommend changing the schema name to a name that does not require quoting.

Comment: Hi @GMB! Thank you for your swift response :)

Unfortunately, I can't change the schema name, it's a public db... 
I tried your solution but it did not work out. 

I got:
LINE 132: from "physionet-data".mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd icd
               ^
Could this be because the from goes first in the code, as follows:

`from "physionet-data".mimiciii_clinical.diagnoses_icd icd
where ...
select ...`

The Github page for the code is there: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/concepts/comorbidity/elixhauser_quan.sql

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "You would need to ensure that the character case the schema was created with matches the one you are using here" please ?

Comment: @LucileTer-Minassian: I mean that if your schema was created with mixed upper/lower case, then you need to use that in your query. See: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: oh, I see! I think the schema is all lower case so we're good on that side. but if double quotation marks don't work, are there other alternatives?